# How to secure Admin SDK Keys on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-admin-sdk, api-key

I am using Google's Admin SDK with my Node backend for auth. Since I am planning to put it on heroku I want to secure my private data. As much as I  know, it's a good idea to secure things like the private key. In my project, I import the config from a json file, like that:

```
  var serviceAccount = require("./AdminSDKFirebase.json");

  admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

And then I have the `AdminSDKFirebase.json` file, where I put the config.

```
  {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

What's the best practice to secure that information, if I want to deploy it to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to store your secrets in environment variables as recommended by Heroku's https://12factor.net/config.

So, export your private key to your heroku app

```
heroku config:set FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY='......'
```

And include it in your configuration object:

```
"private_key": process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY
```

Bonus point is that you can change that key without having to redeploy your app.